# Flagging records that meet a loc groupby query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code which is working at bring back the max record for each id based on date, what I would like to do is have a new column in data2 called flag and have true if it meets this criteria.

```
data2.loc[data2.groupby('id').Date.idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is compare maximal values per groups of Dates:

```
data2['new'] = data2.groupby('id').Date.transform('max').eq(data2.Date)
```

But because `idxmax` return only first possible max value add [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) chained by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
data2['new'] = data2.groupby('id').Date.transform('max').eq(data2.Date) & ~data2.Date.duplicated()
```